# AutoIt Error when charging laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, charging, autoit

This message appears when I charge the laptop (hp)

[image]

and disappears when I remove the charger, tiyfmr.clh file in the message I can't find it in vlegjw folder and vlegjw is hidden and only display when I make all files available to display, I have checked vlegjw folder by McAfee and there is no problem, I hope you can help me in this problem and thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, simply uninstall AutoIt tool. Use standard uninstaller in Programs and Features control panel.

AutoIt is great helper tool, but cases were seen where macros hosted by AutoIt were actually malware. Therefore after uninstalling AutoIt, check your computer for malware/viruses and avoid possible sources of malware.

Removal:

Create system restore point. This allows you to restore your system to time of restore point creation whenever you want.

Verify if you have AutoIt files located in C:\Program Files\AutoIt3. Let me know the result. As next step, we'll have to Run [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and find entries related to tiyfmr.clh or to AutoIt. 
(1) note their full file path, (2) uncheck them and (3) reboot.